# Kernel and Image linear map on polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, problem-solving

I need to find a  kernel and image of a linear map on a polynomial. And also have to solution but I don't understand the following things: why are $X$ and $X^2$ the span of the kernel? 
And how is the image every Rational number?

---

Given question and solution

> **Exercise 2:** $T: P_3 \to \Bbb R$, $T:P(x) \mapsto P(0)$. Determine $\operatorname{Im}(T)$ and $\ker(T)$.

Solution:
\begin{align}
\ker(T) &= \{P(x) \in P_3 \mid P(0) = 0 \}
\\ & = \{P(x) = a + bx + cx^2 \mid P(0) = 0 = a\}
\\ & = \{P(x) = bx + cx^2 \mid b,c \in \Bbb R\}
\\ & = S[x,x^2].
\end{align}
$$
\operatorname{im}(T) = \{r \mid r = P(0) \text{ for } P(x) \in P_3\} = \Bbb R.
$$

[(Image of work so far)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAxoH.jpg)

Comment: it's not the kernel and image of a polynomial; it's the kernel and image of a linear map on polynomials

Comment: Please take the time to type the question instead of posting an external link to it. you can use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to typeset.

Comment: Ben je dan Nederlands?

Comment: @sai-kartik I think that since everything is written neatly and clearly, the question is fine as is

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Thank, I'm from belgium and don't know how those thingies are called in english. Changed the title :)

Comment: @Omnomnomnom België :)

Comment: In the lines on the right side of $\ker(T) = \cdots$, do you understand everything? If not, then what is the first line that you do not understand?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Why is the image every rational number? if T: P(x) -> P(0)?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I thought people here preferred that everything be in the question unless it was absolutely necessary to post an external link?

Comment: the image is every real number, because any real number corresponds to a constant polynomial, which $T$ maps to that real number

Comment: However tidy the penmanship may be, images are nonetheless inaccessible. [Formatting and writing](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10992) from “How to ask a good question.”

Answer (score 1):

To answer each of your questions separately:

> Why is the kernel the span of $X$ and $X^2$?

The fact that $\{P(x) = bx + cx^2 \mid b,c \in \Bbb R\}$ (as in the last line of the derivation) is equal to the span of $x$ and $x^2$ is a direct consequence of the definition of the "span". I recommend that you review the defintion of $S[v_1,\dots,v_n]$.

> How is the image every rational number?

Note that $\Bbb R$ here means the *real* numbers rather than the *rational* numbers. The rational numbers are instead denoted by $\Bbb Q$... for quational.

Consider the following argument: for any $r \in \Bbb R$, $p(x) = 0x^2 + 0x + r$ is a polynomial for which $T(p) = r$. So indeed, *every* real number is an element of the image.

Comment: Actually, the $\Bbb Q$ of the rational numbers stands for "quotients" rather than "quationals".